# Customizing date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery 1.10 . I want to show events for a date on calendar. For this I am using 'datepicker' widget. However I want to change the content of the date appending event information on it. For eg: if there is an event scheduled on 1t July 2013 then on calendar along with the date scheduled, I want to display list of event too.Is there some way to achieve it editing the date text?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Datepicker just adds html content. You can intervene to that content and what you want. But the "how" depends on what you want (can't really visualize the "list of event"). Since the calendar created is dynamic you can inspect the element and see the markup. Copy and paste it in another html file as static and start playing with it until you reach a result (static) that pleases you. After that you can start doing it dynamically since you have a draft of what you want.

PS Since jquery has tons of plugins, have you searched for something more suited for your task? I don't have anything particular in mind, just a thought.